# Should I republish my project while the framework update to a new version?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have some Win Forms/WPF/ASP.NET Core projects published with framework-dependent.

A few days ago I migrated them from .NET Core 3 to .NET 5 preview8 . Today Microsoft published .NET 5 RC1.

In my opinion, I must change the target framework and republish the project if I migrated from .NET Core 3 to .NET 5. But I am not sure whether I should republish the project while just update from .net 5 preview8 to .NET 5 RC1. Or I just need to update the runtime only.

Maybe it is a stupid question but republishes so many projects again is a huge work. Please help me.

Comment: Just curious as to why you would migrate from .net core 3 to .net 5 when it's not production ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because .NET 5 is in-progress of development, you should republish your application. Many fix bug, new feature you need update. Let's see change log: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/5.0/preview/5.0.0-rc.1.md#notable-changes-in-500-rc-1

Answer (score 1):

Today with the RC1 NET 5 is ready (**and licensed**) for production use. So yes, you must update everything again